# Is there a way to let TypeScript know that the values of several variables are linked?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function where multiple different API calls are made, but the core logic surrounding the API calls (error handling, iterating for pagination, etc.) is the same. To avoid duplicating that logic, I'm trying to dynamically call a function and access its results, by passing the function name as a parameter. However, all of the ways I've tried it have resulted in type errors. Here's an example:

```js
interface IApiCaller {
    funcA: (options: { optionFuncA: string }) => Promise<{ keyFuncA: 'a' }>;
    funcB: (options: { optionFuncB: string }) => Promise<{ keyFuncB: 'b' }>;
}

const apiCaller: IApiCaller = {
    funcA: (options: { optionFuncA: string }) => Promise.resolve({ keyFuncA: 'a' }),
    funcB: (options: { optionFuncB: string }) => Promise.resolve({ keyFuncB: 'b' })
};

async function helper<Func extends 'funcA' | 'funcB'>(func: Func) {
    let options: Parameters<IApiCaller[Func]>[0],
        resultsKey: keyof Awaited<ReturnType<IApiCaller[Func]>>;

    if (func === 'funcA') {
        options = { optionFuncA: 'a' };
        resultsKey = 'keyFuncA'; // throws error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
    } else {
        options = { optionFuncB: 'b' };
        resultsKey = 'keyFuncB'; // throws same error as above
    }

    const res = await apiCaller[func](options); // throws error Property 'optionFuncB' is missing in type '{ optionFuncA: string; }' but required in type '{ optionFuncB: string; }'
    const { [resultsKey]: results } = res; 
}
```

Is there a way to let TypeScript know that the values of these variables are linked? In other words, that variables like `options` and `resultsKey` will have the appropriate values corresponding to the value of `func`.

Here's a link to a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEAOwDCcA2+0yA3gLABQy1yMAriAugFzIAUA9pmMByAM6sSyLjz4AxBk1b8wUUAHNkAXwCUyALwA+ZAAUoHALbB+EADzCA1hACekxi2QByOE5VaA3JRq0pAIVZObl4BIRFgiX8ZOUUVdW09A2NTC2RrOyjnACM3ZU9KZUpKBD5ZZDhsPEJoVgxKgiIoTVJvGnoHQNEQwVJwsRB7aWRZeRAlNU0dfSMTCAA6KAh+DnwANwg2K1tBxxdc1QAaVup2hAD2LtKwy4HMkdiJhOnk+cXltY2tjMZzpxy4gpeCiUOD8GyMXyMfrIAAWEHwmGgZkGyAgAA9ICAACb8ZyndBuAA+eP8Ti0bFOrEG6nIVBoRDAfW6rF0cCgcEMEEgUH4ZjquAa0AA2oMALpaIUABlFRzpPmobzo+DA-AA0rZWOkODBkAAlLl0KAgAAqNkRfKwAuqUBFUnFQOOyGAOopUk0Gg0JIcThpjp8N1xnuENx2rD2KiB8poiuVatszSc6R2Tg8yEdylR+FMLTl8oDzWDEVuPzD-2UkajyBjKvVNgTSdJFeohWBuZKAkZb2acAA7nBgIyKlbGkLTqKgv1+KpU4722VhELq3GbKLWEuVM03jOKMogA) with this example set up

Comment: This is essentially the issue of correlated unions as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended approach is described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) where all operations are represented as generic indexed accesses into a simple "mapping" type or mapped types on that type.  If I perform that refactoring here it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOlalN). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This is exactly what I was looking to do, thank you for the refactored example as well as the reference

Comment: @jcalz I actually had an issue trying to use the variable pulled out from the results. Setting the variable works fine, but trying to access any properties on it, like `length` for example, results in the type error `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'IApiCallerRet[K][{ funcA: "keyFuncA"; funcB: "keyFuncB"; }[K]]'`. Is there any way to work around that? In your playground this would correspond to accessing `results.length` after line 28

Comment: ☹ This is why I asked you to check if the approach meets your needs *before* I start working on writing up an answer.  Maybe there is and maybe there isn't a way to work around it, but given that I'm in the middle of writing an answer, I'm not inclined to look into it.  If I wanted to write up an answer without knowing if it met your needs I wouldn't have bothered commenting first.  So, should I keep writing the answer as-is or should I just give up entirely?

Comment: @jcalz This is obviously a genericized example so I can't always know until I apply it to my actual code (which I can't share). I was just asking if there's a workaround for that follow-up issue, your answer already helped me reduce a few of the type errors I was running into. You can still write up your answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: If it's a followup issue I'll take a look later, although it might belong in its own question (unless I can resolve it in a quick comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mutually incompatible ways TypeScript can verify type safety for "correlated" types like this.

One is using values of [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), preferably [discriminated union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), and [narrowing them via control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  This tends to have a block of code per union member.  That's more or less what you're doing with `if (func === 'funcA') { ⋯ } else { ⋯ }`.

The other is using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), where you are performing operations the compiler can see as valid for a whole range of generic type arguments.  This pretty much needs a single block of code that works for all types; you don't break it into cases.  That's more or less what you're doing with `const res = await apiCaller[func](options);`.

And currently these approaches are mutually incompatible.  If you want to write a single block of code that works for all cases, you'll need to use generics and not unions.  And if you want to write case-specific blocks, then you'll want to use unions and not generics.

---

This mismatch where you can't use unions in a single block is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and a recommended refactoring to use generics is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

I'm going to go through that refactoring with your example, to get generic operations the compiler can follow.  Generally speaking the compiler is good at performing generic *indexing operations* represented as [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), so you can simulate case-by-case code with an object property lookup.  And in order for a single line of code like `apiCaller[func](options)` to be seen as acceptable, the type of `apiCaller[func]` needs to be a function type like `(arg: XXX) => YYY` where `options` is of type `XXX`, so `apiCaller` will need to be of a specially curated type where `XXX` is some generic type depending on the type of `func`.  This tends to be where you defined it as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over some "base" mapping object types.

Here's how it looks.

First let's rename your original `IApiCaller` type out of the way:

```
interface _IApiCaller {
    funcA: (options: { optionFuncA: string }) => Promise<{ keyFuncA: 'a' }>;
    funcB: (options: { optionFuncB: string }) => Promise<{ keyFuncB: 'b' }>;
}
```

Then we make the "base" mapping object types.  First one corresponding to the *argument* types for the `IApiCaller` methods:

```
type IApiCallerArg = { [K in keyof _IApiCaller]:
    Parameters<_IApiCaller[K]>[0]
};
/* type IApiCallerArg = {
    funcA: { optionFuncA: string; };
    funcB: { optionFuncB: string; };
} */
```

And then one corresponding to the *return* types:

```
type IApiCallerRet = { [K in keyof _IApiCaller]:
    Awaited<ReturnType<_IApiCaller[K]>>
};
/* type IApiCallerRet = {
    funcA: { keyFuncA: 'a'; };
    funcB: { keyFuncB: 'b'; };
} */
```

And finally we rewrite `IApiCaller` as a mapped type on those two:

```
type IApiCaller = { [K in keyof _IApiCaller]:
    (options: IApiCallerArg[K]) => Promise<IApiCallerRet[K]>
};
/* type IApiCaller = {
    funcA: (options: { optionFuncA: string; }) => Promise<{ keyFuncA: 'a'; }>;
    funcB: (options: { optionFuncB: string; }) => Promise<{ keyFuncB: 'b'; }>;
} */
```

Now at this point you might think "isn't that exactly the type I started with"?  Well, they are equivalent, but the new `IApiCaller` is explicitly written as a mapping over a generic `K` key, and the compiler can use that to resolve things inside a generic function in a way it just can't with the old definition.  In what follows you might try to replace the new definition with the old one and see all your errors come back.

So `apiCaller` is annotated as the new `IApiCaller` type and it works:

```
const apiCaller: IApiCaller = {
    funcA: (options: { optionFuncA: string }) => Promise.resolve({ keyFuncA: 'a' }),
    funcB: (options: { optionFuncB: string }) => Promise.resolve({ keyFuncB: 'b' })
};
```

And now let's write your generic `helper()` function:

```
async function helper<K extends keyof IApiCaller>(func: K) {
    const optionsMap: IApiCallerArg = {
        funcA: { optionFuncA: 'a' },
        funcB: { optionFuncB: 'b' }
    }
    const options = optionsMap[func];

    const resultsKeyMap: { [K in keyof IApiCaller]: keyof IApiCallerRet[K] } = {
        funcA: 'keyFuncA',
        funcB: 'keyFuncB'
    }
    const resultsKey = resultsKeyMap[func];

    const res = await apiCaller[func](options);
    const results = res[resultsKey];
    return results;

}
```

Recall that we can't use case-by-case analysis to get `options` and `resultsKey` that work in a generic function, but we *can* use generic property lookups.  So `optionsMap` and `resultsKeyMap` are objects of appropriate types so that we can index each with `func` and get a continued generic output.  So `options` is of type `IApiCallerArg[K]` and `resultsKey` is of type `keyof IApiCallerRet[K]`.

And then `await apiCaller[func](options)` compiles with no error; the type of `apiCaller[func](options)` is seen as `Promise<IApiCallerRet[K]>`, so `res` is of type `IApiCallerRet[K]`, and so `results` is of type `IApiCallerRet[K][keyof IapiCallerRet[K]]`, which is sufficiently generic for the output to be strongly typed:

```
const a = helper("funcA"); // const a: Promise<"a">
const b = helper("funcB"); // const b: Promise<"b">
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPoEkCCAHYBhOAG0OmQG8BYAKGVuRgFcQFMAuZACgHtsxguQAZ3ZlkPPgIBiTFu0FgooAObIAvgEpkAXgB8yAApQuAW2CCIAHlEBrCAE9pzNsgDkcF2p0BuanXoyAIXZuXn4hETFQqUC5BWU1TV0DI1NzK2RbBxjXACMPVW9qVWpqMDtsFCxcAmJoTCgVLXJkAG0AaWRQDPsuGDQq-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)